# ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row - issue

Tags: sql, oracle

```
update dsalesinvoicehdr set paymentterms = ( select pt.termcode from dsalesinvoicehdr dsh
       inner join mg_subledger mp on mp.mg_subledgerid = dsh.customer 
       inner join mg_partytbill mb on mb.bsubledger = mp.subledgercode  
       left join payterm pt on pt.paytermid = mb.paymentterm)
```

> ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

how to resolve this issue. pls help

Comment: It's saying your sub-query returns more than one row which means it cannot be used as a `SET` value.

Comment: @Max, With `update dsalesinvoicehdr set paymentterms = ()` you ask Oracle to assign a single value selected by subquery to  `paymentterms` in every row of `dsalesinvoicehdr` table. But your subquery returns more than one row, so Oracle don't know which value to set

Answer (score 1):

Will cause this error because your subquery returns multiple pieces of information Your subquery return multi-row data

You can use `UPDATE` and `JOIN`

```
update
( 
select pt.termcode,dsh.paymentterms 
from dsalesinvoicehdr dsh
inner join mg_subledger mp on mp.mg_subledgerid = dsh.customer 
inner join mg_partytbill mb on mb.bsubledger = mp.subledgercode  
left join payterm pt on pt.paytermid = mb.paymentterm
) t
set  t.termcode= t.paymentterms
```

Answer (score 0):

Use update and join mate!!

```
update
( 
   select pt.termcode,dsh.paymentterms 
   from dsalesinvoicehdr dsh
   inner join mg_subledger mp on mp.mg_subledgerid = dsh.customer 
   inner join mg_partytbill mb on mb.bsubledger = mp.subledgercode  
   left join payterm pt on pt.paytermid = mb.paymentterm
) tab
set  tab.termcode= tab.paymentterms
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to select one of the values.  To common methods are an aggregation function or `where rownum = 1`:

```
update dsalesinvoicehdr
    set paymentterms = (select pt.termcode
                        from dsalesinvoicehdr dsh inner join
                             mg_subledger mp
                             on mp.mg_subledgerid = dsh.customer inner join
                             mg_partytbill mb
                             on mb.bsubledger = mp.subledgercode join
                             payterm pt
                             on pt.paytermid = mb.paymentterm
                        where rownum = 1
                       );
```

You don't need the `left join` in the subquery.  Non-matches will result in `NULL` anyway.